# Add new <option> to all dropdown <select> tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to add a Drop down menu option "Please select" to the top of each drop-down list on a page to be selected by default, using something similar like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('select option[value="PSC"]').attr("selected",true);
};
```

and this is what im using for the drop-down:

```
window.onload = function AddItem(text,value) {
    // Create an Option object
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    // Add an Option object to Drop Down/List Box
    document.getElementsByTagName("option").options.add(opt);
    // Assign text and value to Option object
    opt.text = 'Please select...';
    opt.value = 'Please Select';  
}
```

I'm new at javascript, can someone point me in the right direction to compiling this together so that when the page loads every drop-down list gets a default selected option called "Please select"

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified you pure javascript function to this function **(This does not affect the already selected option) [DEMO jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vrr5/1/)**

```
     window.onload = function AddItem(text, value) {

        // Get all Drop Down/List Box in document
        var sel = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

        for (var x = 0; x < sel.length; x++) {

           // Create an Option object and set it's value/text
           var opt = document.createElement("option");
           opt.text = 'Please select...';
           opt.value = 'Please Select';

           //prepend in select box
           sel[x].insertBefore(opt, sel[x].options[0])
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $('<option>', {
      text     : 'Please select...',
      value    : 'Please select...',
      selected :  true
   }).prependTo('select');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gsp9b/

Or:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
    opt = '';
for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    opt = document.createElement("option");
    // opt.selected = true;
    opt.text = 'Please select...';
    opt.value = 'Please Select';
    select[i].options.add(opt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Anyway to modify it so that it doesn't effect drop-down lists where there already is a selected value?

Comment: You're awesome! Not to be picky, but how to assign it to the top of the list and to append it to the bottom?

Comment: @Tower Do you want to append the options instead of prepending them? If yes, you can use `appendTo` method, `.appendTo('select');`. the second code also appends the new options.

Comment: Sorry had a spelling error there, i mean to place it to the top of the list. The current code you have beginning with var select place the option to the bottom of the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$('select').prepend('<option>Please select...</option>');
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Anyway to modify it so that it doesn't effect drop-down lists where there already is a selected value?

Comment: @Tower I think better approach is to add to all selects option on the back-end side or to all on the front-end side. Having two different way of building select in the same app is hard to maintenance and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("select").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Please select</option>");
});
```

Comment: Happy to discover that jQuery's [`prepend`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L50) uses `insertBefore`, so these methods won't destroy and re-create the other childnodes even though a HTML string is passed to it :D

Comment: @PaulS. Not sure what you mean. Can you explain? Thx.

Comment: I was expecting it to be a simple `.innerHTML = str + .innerHTML;`, but it actually creates a document fragments and uses the DOM method `insertBefore` to insert them into the document keeping what was there -- if you modify with `.innerHTML`, you destroy what was there before.