# Change position of an option using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a dropdown list with several options and now I want to insert a new option to the top of the list. How do I do that?

```
function insertOptionAll (DOMtarget)
{
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Some option";
    option.value = 0;
    option.title = "Some option";
    DOMtarget.add(option); //appends to the end
    //DOMtarget.options[DOMtarget.options.length - 1].index = 0; --> doesnt work
}
```

Comment: can you show where DOMtarget is coming from (and what it is)

Comment: query: `$('#yourlist').prepend(option)`, basically. the new option is a dom element like any other. use dom operations to insert it wherever you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912831/how-to-insert-option-at-specified-index-of-selectmultiple-in-html

Comment: I saw the solution with jQuery but I'm not using it in this project.
The `target` comes from another function and is created using `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ...

```
DOMtarget.insertBefore(option, DOMtarget.options[0]);
```

See: [Add new <option> to all dropdown <select> tags using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379789/add-new-option-to-all-dropdown-select-tags-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertOption(selectId) {
    var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Some option";
    option.value = 0;
    option.title = "Some option";
    selectList.insertBefore(option, selectList.options[0]);
}
```